# wPF VisualTreeHelper.GetParent returns wrong class?

Tags: wpf

I have the following XAML defined.

```
<Popup x:Class="EMS.Controls.Dictionary.MapTip"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
    PopupAnimation="Slide"
     AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Mouse"       
       x:Name="root"                   
      >

    <Popup.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Popup.Resources>
    <Viewbox x:Name="viewBox" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="mainGrid">

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Popup>
```

If I walk up the visual tree using VisualTreeHelper.GetParent from "mainGrid", I eventually get System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupRoot, but never get the Popup itself.  Anyone with a theory on why this is and what I can do about it?  I neeed Popup and not PopupRoot.

TIA.

Comment: Does it work if you use `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()` instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The content in a popup is added to a different visual tree with a parent which is the PopupRoot but you can use the logical tree helper to get the popup with this snippet :

```
LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()
```

**From MSDN :**

> When you add content to a Popup control, the Popup control becomes the logical parent to the content. Similarly, the Popup content is considered to be the logical child of the Popup. The child content is not added to the visual tree that contains the Popup control. Instead, the child content is rendered in a separate window that has its own visual tree when the IsOpen property is set to true.

++

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys.

Answer (score 5):

Try walking the Logical tree and not the Visual tree

```
LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()
```

Answer (score 5):

`LogicalTreeHelper` is unable to reach the Popup as well the best one could do is try using the Name the "PopupRoot" to compare to `GetType().Name`.

Comment: The logical tree does contain Popup, just recursively walk it. It is there.

Comment: In my case, the logical parent of my logical parent is null. In my case, I have to traverse the visual tree up to the PopupRoot and then it's Logical Parent is the Popup. Unfortunately I can't search for a parent of type PopupRoot since PopupRoot is internal to it's package. Also, there is no existing method for getting the Visual Root, which in this case would be the PopupRoot. I don't want to write an extension method to get the Visual Root just for a single situation. So I currently do not have a solution.

Comment: Best solution I can do is to traverse to the highest level user element inside the Popup, which I dislike because of maintainability. What happens when someone changes the structure inside the popup but don't update this code? It will not function as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
Popup oPopup = VisualHelper.GetLogicalParent<Popup>(oThumb);
```

...

```
public static T GetLogicalParent<T>(DependencyObject p_oElement)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject oParent = p_oElement;
    Type oTargetType = typeof(T);
    do
    {
        oParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(oParent);
    }
    while (
        !(
            oParent == null
            || oParent.GetType() == oTargetType
            || oParent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(oTargetType)
        )
    );

    return oParent as T;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CloseScatterViewItem((SurfaceButton)sender);
    }

    private void CloseScatterViewItem(SurfaceButton button)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = button;
        while ((parent as ScatterViewItem) == null)
        {

            // Get the next parent.
            parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) != null ? LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) : VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            ScatterViewItem item = parent as ScatterViewItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                DependencyObject scatterView = item;
                while ((scatterView as ScatterView) == null)
                {
                    scatterView = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(scatterView) != null ? LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(scatterView) : VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(scatterView);
                    ScatterView FoundSV = scatterView as ScatterView;
                    if (FoundSV != null)
                    {
                        //FoundSV.Items.Remove(item);
                        FadeOutAndRemove(FoundSV, item);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static void FadeOutAndRemove(ScatterView sv, ScatterViewItem svi)
    {
        try
        {
            svi.Opacity = 1.0;

            var a = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 1.0,
                To = 0.0,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
            };

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(a);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(a, svi);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

            storyboard.Completed += delegate
            {
                svi.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                sv.Items.Remove(svi);
                svi.Content = null;
                svi = null;
            };

            storyboard.Begin();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle error

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29628668/5358284) and the answers presented here (and thanks to a comment by Wouter), I finally came up with this:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

public static class FamilyHelper
{
    public static T FindAncestor<T>(this DependencyObject dObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var uiElement = dObj;
        while (uiElement != null)
        {
            uiElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(uiElement as Visual ?? new UIElement())
                ?? VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(uiElement as Visual3D ?? new UIElement())
                ?? LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(uiElement);

            if (uiElement is T) return (T) uiElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

which never goes wrong and works for all types of controls, e.g.

```
var element = sender as UIElement;
var parentWindow = element.FindAncestor<Window>();
```

Comment: This throws an exception when dependencyObject is not a Visual or Visual3D. You should replace the ?? line with current is Visual || current is Visual3D ? VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current) : LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

Comment: @Wouter : Sorry but that's nonsense. The `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` method throws exception only when `dependencyObject` is null. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/ms608747(v=vs.105))

Comment: The link seems broken. But you might want to check for any contentelement like for example a textelement.